# About the csstransition effect on click event

Tags: css

I creat a toggle-menu like the [DEMO](http://demo.85ryan.com/menu/index.html), i want to add a csstransition effect on Hide and Show menu by click the Menu Button, So how can i do?

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Menu Demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>
            <div class="nav-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates, consequuntur, nemo exercitationem in eum adipisci non eligendi sed ratione delectus nam quisquam ipsa debitis molestiae assumenda facere odit laborum officiis!</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Read transition docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 ( function( $ ) {
  /**
   * Enables menu toggle for small screens.
   */
  ( function() {
   var nav = $( '#site-navigation' ), button, menu;
   if ( ! nav )
    return;

   button = nav.find( '.menu-toggle' );
   menu   = nav.find( '.nav-menu' );
   if ( ! button )
    return;

   // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
   if ( ! menu || ! menu.children().length ) {
    button.hide();
    return;
   }

   $( '.menu-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
    nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
   } );
  } )();
 } )( jQuery );
 </script>    //this is the JS CODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i saw you used `display:none` on your `ul`.
if you want to use jquery transitions like `slideToggle` `orFadeIN` `fadeOut`,
  its good but if you want to use css transitions you sholud have another approch.
you should make it `height` and/or `width` to `0` (depends on the effect you like to have),
then make another class like that and with each click you can use `switchClass` (with jqueryui) or `addClass/removeClass`. then give the transitions to `width/height`.
and lala its works

Comment: something i forgot!: add `overflow:hidden` to your first class thus it won't show the content on width/height 0 and dont forget to accept the answer